# Como Actualizar un id con Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hola gente tengo un problema con id no puedo actualizar un ID por si hay un mensaje sin ver así como `facebook`

quiero que id de usuario se actualize pero no Funciona espero que me ayuden amigos

HTML:

```
<div id="'.$fila['userID'].'" class="Pending_messages_user"></div>
```

JS:

```
function actualizar(){

    var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var datauser = 'user_id='+ user_id ;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'codigo.php',
        data: datauser,
        success: function(respuesta) {

        //Pegamos el contenido de update2.php en la div id#Pending_messages_user
        $('.Pending_messages_user').html(respuesta);
   }
});
}

setInterval( function(){
    actualizar();   
},1000)//Actualizamos cada 1 segundo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es muy sencillo... Tu por ajax estas enviando el id y en tu controlador PHP cambias la variable. Pero para poder ver el cambio en tu HTML tienes que "refrescar" la pagina para que cambie los ID utilizando la variable de php así como lo haces... Lo que puedes hacer es usar JS para inyectar los nuevos ID que recibes de AJAX.

```
funcion success(response){
  for(int i = 0, i < response.length; i++){
      $("div[id="+response[i].anterior+"]).attr("id",response.nuevo);
  }
}
```

Algo por el estilo me imagino yo... Así cambias los ID de manera dinámica. No puedes cambiarlos directamente así con PHP, recuerda que cuando carga la pagina se pinta ese $fila['userID'] pero una vez pintado es estático no dinámico.

Comment: El resultado es en tiempo real los que pasa es se actualizan todos al mismo tiempo y antes de que digas que es problema está en el PHP no yo en estos de JS no soy muy bueno

Comment: Ah no, yo no digo que el problema esta en PHP, lo que digo es que asi como lo intentas hacer no funciona. Pero si lo haces asi como te dejo en el ejemplo harias el cambio dinamico sin problema.

Comment: ok voy a hacer caso a ver que pasa :)

Comment: no poes si tenias razo me funciono al 100% solo mira esto Gracias amigo por tu ayuda otra cosa en unos dias voy sacar un beta del sitio no se si quieres probarla y otra ves Gracias https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eD14.png

Comment: Claro, con mucho gusto. Envíame el link y soy parte de la open beta! saludos.

Comment: https://demochat.000webhostapp.com Beta